# Query with two posttypes and two different meta_keys

Tags: wp-query

I need to query two custom post types,

like this:

```
'post_type' => array ('single_events', 'group_of_events'),
```

and i need to select certain posts in a certain order, to do this i wrote a meta query to select posts between two dates stored in a custom field.

my problem is now:
for my first custom post type this works well, these posts only have the field for start-date.

but for my second custom post type i need to use another key for the meta_query, because these posts are events with an start-date and an end-date,

so my question is how is it possible to modify the meta query to select the posts

for single_events

```
by meta_key =>'start_date'
```

and for group_of_events

```
by meta_key =>'end_date'
```

at the moment it looks like this:

```
'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            'time' => array(
                'key' => 'start_date', /// or 'end_date' for cpt 'group_of_events??
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                'type' => 'DATE',
                'value' => array($filter_start_date, $filter_end_date),
                ),
            'type' => array(
                'key' => 'type',
                'compare' => 'IN',
                'value' => $filter_type,
                ), 
            ),
'orderby' => 'time',
```

i probably could give the single_events also an enddate just by cloning the start_date but maybe there is a more elegant way to do this?

thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
 'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'start_date', /// or 'end_date' for cpt 'group_of_events??
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type' => 'DATE',
            'value' => array($filter_start_date, $filter_end_date),
            ),
        array(
            'key' => 'end_date', /// or 'end_date' for cpt 'group_of_events??
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type' => 'DATE',
            'value' => array($filter_start_date, $filter_end_date),
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'type',
            'compare' => 'IN',
            'value' => $filter_type,
            ), 
        ),
```

then you can change the start_date of the events to another key.

Comment: thank you! but I cant change the key fields, it is not possible to include the post type in the meta query, right? like  ` 'meta_query' => array('relation' => 'OR',   array( 'post_type'=>'FIELDKEY' 'key' => 'start_date',  ` …